# Passing char* to a function c++

Tags: c++, function, char

So I've this issue I can't get fixed :-(
In my .h I've this:

```
protected:
   char* _textPath_1;
   FileReader* _reader_3;
```

in .cpp I've:

```
_reader_3 = new FileReader();
_textPath_1 = "foo";
_reader_3->openFile(_textPath_1);
```

And FileReader has this:

```
private:
   char* fileName;
public:
   signed int openFile(char* name);
```

but If I write this (just to test):

```
signed int FileReader::openFile(char* name) {
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
    fileName = name;
    stream.open(fileName, std::ios::in);
    if (!stream.is_open()) {
        FileReader::printErrorOpeningFile(fileName);
        stream.close();
        return -1;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

fileName is a char * and I need that it gets the same value (foo) of name. I get an error, and I'm not even able to print name, it just print a blank line.. why?

EDIT: it's not working even using strcpy.. Actually inside the function I can't print the value of name, it's like it has been "deininitialized"

Comment: Why do you want to mess around with char * in C++ when you have std::string?

Comment: By the way, are you really trying to assign a char * to another variable of type char *??? You need to use `strcpy` for that...

Comment: It's crashing on fileName = name;

Comment: And also I can't read name inside my function

Comment: what is the type of fileName? And what is the value of _reader_3 pointer?

Comment: fileName is a char* and reader3 it's a Filereader()

Comment: Can you reduce the problem to a minimal, but complete program? One that compiles, but still has the problem? The code you have now should at least print "foo", even if other things won't work, so the problem must lay elsewhere.

Comment: so, my programs compile and unfortunately it's not possible to reduce it (like thousands and thousands of lines)..

Comment: I think what Mr Lister means, is that you write a simple programm that compiles and has the same crashing. We are not psychic here ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space for your text string `_textPath_1`.
Try this instead.

```
char myTextString[] = "foo";
_textPath_1 = myTextString;
```

This creates a local character array (a character string), which is initialized to `"foo\0"`. It then copies that character string's address to your char pointer `_textPath_1`. As a **LOCAL** storage, it will only be valid in the local code block and will not be usable once your code has dropped out of its scope. If you need that string past the local code block, you will need to allocate it from heap memory (using `new` for instance) and remember to deallocate it after you are done with it.

You cannot use `strcpy` with your unallocated pointer because `strcpy` expects the destination `char*` to be pointing at a character array acting as your destination string buffer. As you haven't allocated any char space at all, it cannot copy `"foo"` into your `_textPath_1`, and that's why you get a runtime error when you try to `strcpy` it.

These and other fun with `char*` is why `std::string` was invented. No worries about allocating and deallocating space, having to use strcpy to copy its value, etc etc etc. Consider using `std::string _textPath_1` in place of your `char* _textPath_1`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate _reader_3 before calling the function.

FileReader* _reader_3 = new FileReader;

I assume fileName is your member variable. Accessing pointers without initialization will result in unpredictable results

Comment: Ok, maybe next time I'll post something it's better If i write everyhing :-D _reader_3 it's already allocated

Comment: can u copy paste the whole file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're really defining global variables in your header file:

```
char* _textPath_1;
FileReader* _reader_3;
```

Then you shouldn't be doing that. Global variables should be declared in header files, but defined in an implementation file.

---

This code works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct FileReader {
    char* fileName;
    std::fstream stream;

    signed int FileReader::openFile(char* name) {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
        fileName = name;
        stream.open(fileName, std::ios::in);
        if (!stream.is_open()) {
            FileReader::printErrorOpeningFile(fileName);
            stream.close();
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void printErrorOpeningFile(char *) {}
};

int main() {
    char* _textPath_1;
    FileReader* _reader_3;

    _reader_3 = new FileReader();
    _textPath_1 = "foo";
    _reader_3->openFile(_textPath_1);
    delete _reader_3;
}
```

Comment: They're defined in a protected block in my .h file

Comment: protected how? Do you mean that they're actually not global variables, and are in fact class instance variables with an access specifier of 'protected:'? You ought to call out exactly what they are in your question.

Comment: ok.. just edited my question.. anyway: yes! They are in a protected: block

Comment: The fact that they're protected isn't as relevant as the fact that they're instance variables. You should edit you question to contain an complete, buildable (but small) program that shows the issue. Otherwise people will keep guessing at what the program is and point out errors that relate to their guesses, not necessarily your actual problem.